# Introductory books on complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I'm a senior in my undergrad. years of college, and I haven't taken Complex Analysis yet.

I have taken Real Analysis I (covered properties of $\mathbb{R}$, set theory, limits of sequences and functions, series, (uniform) continuity, uniform convergence) and Abstract Algebra I (covered $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, an intro to group theory (groups, subgroups, quotient groups, isomorphism theorems, semidirect products), and an intro to ring theory (fields, ideals)).

The book that we use at the university I attend isn't very analytical, from my understanding. (The book is *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering, Science, and Mathematics*, 3rd ed. by Saff.) Of the courses I've taken in my undergrad, Real Analysis I has definitely been my favorite course so far, and I will be taking Real Analysis II (covers integration and differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, Riemman-Stieltjes, and some other topics that I don't know about) this upcoming fall.

Are there any books on complex analysis that you would suggest given my background? Thank you!

**Edit**: Other courses I have taken: I have taken Calculus I through III (nothing on Differential Equations - although I do know what a first-order linear differential equation is), actuarial science courses (Probability (Calculus-based), Statistics (Calculus-based), Life Contingencies), and Linear Algebra (one semester using Larson's *Elementary Linear Algebra* and a second semester independent study using Axler).

Comment: @GitGud I'm assuming he has calculus integration, just not the "formal" real analysis version of integration. I could be wrong, but, at least states-side, most people who take a class called "real analysis" have already taken calculus.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh. Where I come from mathematicians don't even take calculus, so I didn't consider that. Maybe the OP can give some more context regarding his situation. **Edit:** and he already did.

Comment: I can go ahead and do that.

Comment: @Clarinetist You already did, but there's no harm is adding it to the question. And by the way, you should also say wether you're into visual stuff. There are a lot of complex analysis books which are very pictorial while others not so much.

Comment: What text are you using for Real Analysis I, II?

Comment: @amWhy - Real Analysis I uses Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis*, and Real Analysis II uses Protter's *A First Course in Real Analysis*.

Comment: @GitGud - Yes, I am definitely a fan of "visual stuff." :)

Comment: @Clarinetist If you like visual stuff, _Visual Complex Analysis_ by Tristan Needham is very visual. When I read it, I liked to supplement it with a more rigorous text, like Krantz's and/or Ahlfors' Complex Analysis books.

Comment: @ClarinetistI voted to close this question as a duplicate because there lots of suggestion on the other question (in the comment above). I'm guessing you can manage with those.

Comment: @GitGud - That's fine. I think Gamelin looks good for my purposes. I'm not quite sure how to close this question, though.

Comment: @Clarinetist You don't have to do anything nor are you supposed to. The users with enough reputation can decide to vote to close it if they think closing is appropiate. When $5$ people vote to close, the system will close the question.

Comment: @GitGud - Ah, okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you look at [Gamelin](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~twg/)'s book [Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950699). It is suitable for a good undergraduate who's already had some real analysis.

Comment: [This](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~twg/CA.book.html) might be helpful.

Comment: +1 for this excellent recommendation. Great for self study.

Answer (score 2):

Should throw my mortarboard into the ring and plug Hilary Priestley's [*Introduction to Complex Analysis*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Complex-Analysis-H-Priestley/dp/0198525621). I'm certainly finding it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend D.J. Newman & J. Bak's  *Complex Analysis*

http://books.google.ch/books/about/Complex_Analysis.html?id=MKPe1Q9k-nAC&redir_esc=y

It is clear, "short" and contains all the basics on complex analysis. A tthe end of the book you can find some advanced topics like infinite products and special functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at an academic institution, you may have free access to this problem book through your library: http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-0348-0077-8