# Book on Geometry (GRE Math Subject Test)?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, gre-exam

I *don't believe* that this is a duplicate of any question that is on this site.

I am currently searching for a geometry textbook which covers (at least) material for the GRE Math **Subject** Test. I have never taken a course on Geometry (since high school), but I have gone through all of the courses listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419439/introductory-books-on-complex-analysis).

Are there any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: None of the items at these two matched your driteria? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107882/geometry-book-recommendation?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/books-on-classical-geometry?rq=1

Comment: I wasn't sure about the second link due to the "advanced treatment" criteria. Now the first one looks good (didn't find it before), except I'm not sure if the GRE covers some non-Euclidean geometry (the course at the university I attend, if I were to take it, would cover some of that), since the syllabus just mentions "geometry."

Comment: geometry like...differential geometry? or...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend AMSCO's Geometry

http://www.herricks.org/highschool.cfm?subpage=11368

It is free and it even has a solution manual. It is even great when you are in college

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a little bit more time to see if I can get some other answers, since I would think that there would be more people that would know more about this topic...

Comment: Hey do you still have such a reference? It's no longer available there...thanks!