# Which book on complex analysis is good for self study?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers, book-recommendation, several-complex-variables

**Which book on complex analysis is good for self study?**

I am an average student and have just a very basic knowledge of this subject. I want to cover up to Runge's Theorem.

I heard about few books- Gamelin's Complex Analysis; a text by Churchill and another Ahlfors' Complex analysis.

Thank you.

Comment: I like Ahlfors' a lot.

Comment: @SaraTancredi: Maybe review these two postings: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419439/introductory-books-on-complex-analysis?rq=1, Regards

Comment: Thank you Tunococ and Amzoti.

Comment: OFF: good luck; I found math self-study incedibly hard, especially in English, which is a foreign language for me.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt But I find self study more interesting. Actually, your English is not bad. Look, you are writing very well. The problems is that you are indulged in many other extra curricular activities :)

Comment: @SaraTancredi indeed, selfstuding is definitely interesting. Also, even if I write well, understanding some special words and sentences is hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gamelin is quite good. After or together with it, I recommend you to read the following.

- Reinhold Remmert. *Theory of complex functions*. Springer 1991.

Then there is the second volume:

- Reinhold Remmert. *Classical topics in complex function theory*. Springer 2010.

Answer (score 12):

Nice link ;)

- Visual Complex Analysis (Tristan Needham)
- Visual Complex Functions:An introduction with phase portraits (Elias Wegert)

Enjoy Them...

Comment: I've also downloaded these texts. they look cool. Thanks Ricardo.

Answer (score 2):

Gilman, Kra and Rodriguez, wrote the excellent book "Complex Analysis in the Spirit of Lipman Bers". It has everything you need to study complex analysis and has great exercises.

Comment: I will see it. Thanks Robert Auffarth. 
http://libgen.net/view.php?id=924940