# Book Recommendation For Complex Analysis

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for suggestions in regard to a good first book on Complex analysis, preferably the book will be more so introductory if possible as It will be my first time studying the subject. I am familiarity with calculus and some analysis and algebra.

Even any PDF notes or things of that nature could help, thanks a lot!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419439/introductory-books-on-complex-analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Invitation to Complex Analysis](http://www.maa.org/pubs/ICA.html) by Ralph P. Boas (second edition revised by Harold P. Boas).

Answer (score 0):

These are my go to books For Complex Analysis. The first book I believe is a fantastic introduction to Complex analysis, while the other three are more advanced.

Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham

Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors

Real and Complex Analysis by Walter Rudin

Functions of One Complex variable vol I by John B. Conway

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.math.unipd.it/~pietro/Analisi_complessa.html "basic complex analysis" and "selected topics in complex analysis" are **really** good notes.